# Confusion around passing assumed const parameter in constructor

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to Dart (and Flutter) so this might be very obvious but for the life of me I cannot make sense of why this is an issue.

I am trying to construct a few utility classes, understanding Flutter loves to pre-calculate as much as possibly by encouraging **const** values everywhere, makes sense to me to want to do that! Hoping to do right by Flutter and our app's performance I've written the following (names changed from original):

**Below: works great**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MainPackageAssetImage extends AssetImage {
  const MainPackageAssetImage(String assetName)
      : super(assetName, package: 'main_package');
}
...
// Works as expected, enforces constructor is called with const value (even if that is a const variable) 
final assetImage = MainPackageAssetImage("exampleImageName"); 

// Fails as expected, whooHooAssetName is not a const value
var whooHooAssetName = "whoo hoo";
...
final invalidCallAssetImage = MainPackageAssetImage(whooHooAssetName);
```

**Below: results in an error before it's even called with const or non-const passed `assetName`s**: *Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions. Try making the argument a valid constant, or use 'new' to call the constructor*

```dart
class MainPackageImage extends Image {
  const MainPackageImage(String assetName)
      : super(image: const MainPackageAssetImage(assetName));
}
```

Dart complains about `assetName`'s usage in the construction of `MainPackageAssetImage` that is passed to the `MainPackageImage`'s `image` parameter rather than enforcing that `assetName` is a **const** at the calling point like in the first example.

I'm unclear why within `MainPackageAssetImage`'s constructor `assetName`'s **const** enforcement is given off to the caller where that same passing the buck isn't allowed for `MainPackageImage`'s constructor (asking that `MainPackageImage`'s caller be responsible for passing a **const** value rather than making it `MainPackageImage`'s responsibility being the immediate caller). Is this a limitation of Dart's resolution or am I missing a core concept somewhere?

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got your question right, but I'll try to explain what I think you misunderstood.

`const` values have to be known at compile time. Using a `const` constructor enables a class to be constructed at compile time **but still allows the creation of the object at runtime**.

```dart
class A {
    final String s;
    const A(String? myString) : s = myString ?? 'Empty';
}

// Will be created at compile time
const a1 = A("bla");

// Will be created at runtime
final a2 = A(getUserInput());
```

Now let's apply this to your example:

```dart
final image = MainPackageImage(getUserInput());
```

In this case a non-const user input is passed to `MainPackageImage` which is perfectly fine. However inside the constructor of `MainPackageImage` the following happens.

```dart
const innerImage = MainPackageAssetImage(assetName);
super(image: innerImage);
```

Dart however cannot know the value of `assetName` at compile time. Therefore the error is raised.

Comment: If I understand what you're illustrating I think this is a different example. The point I'm trying to understand is that Dart is comfortable resolving that `MainPackageAssetImage("blah")` works just fine by putting it on the caller of the constructor to provide a const value, however Dart is unable to elevate that requirement though the contents of `MainPackageImage`'s constructor, even if `MainPackageImage("blah")` were called. It doesn't even let that call happen, it gives that error on the constructor contents itself. Does that make sense?